# How to minimize duplication code in Android without creating Objects

Tags: android

I have multiple activities in which I want to use same code in those activity.
I finished it with having same bunch of code in each activity.
How can minimize this redundant code.
For doing this I dont want to create object and use it's methods for removing redundancy...

Plz help...
Thank U....

Comment: why don't you want to use another object to reduce redundancy?

Comment: @JacobPhillips : coz I have read, creating objects may cost in terms of resources, performance etc. Its not recommended in mobile application...   Hey let me know if I m wrong... I m new to android...

Comment: I think you should have common ("redundant") methods and include them in a new class that your other activities inherit from. You do want to be conscious of memory usage, but creating a fairly simple object is perfectly acceptable in this (and most) situations

Comment: You can can create a "BaseActivity" and include a lot code in that single class and then simply create classes and extend that "BaseActivity".

Comment: @MasterJB : I will use ur option... thankx..

Comment: @NareshJagadale, Is that the answer you are looking for?

Comment: @MasterJB , ya I just want to know multiple options for doing this... thnkx.

Comment: @MasterJB , i cant vote for ur answer as my reputation is not more than 15.. :)

Comment: You cant even set the answer as correct? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the solution is simple:   extends the class Activity, and add him all the methods you want.
(I usually call this class BaseActivity for instance)
then, when you are developing new activity - instead of extend the class Activity -  extends the class BaseActivity you've made, which contain the methods you added..

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
protected int mSomeValue;

protected void someMethod1()
{

}

protected void someMethod2()
{

}

protected void someMethod3()
{

}

}

class SomeActivity extends BaseActivity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    someMethod1();
}
}

class SomeActivity2 extends BaseActivity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    someMethod1();
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can can create a "BaseActivity" and include a lot code in that single class and then simply create classes and extend that "BaseActivity".

Here is what I think you are looking for:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}   

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.donate:  
        //something
        break;

    case R.id.about_menuitem:  
        //something
        break;

    case R.id.exit:  
        finish();
        break;         

    default:
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}   
}
```

I created a class called "BaseActivity", in this class I have my Android options menu and I also extend "Activity". Since I extended "Activity" and have my options menu in this class, I can now use this same menu code for all my other classes.

I just simply create my new classes and extend them with "BaseActivity":

```
public class SomeOtherActivity extends BaseActivity {
 //new code here
}
```

Now the class called "SomeOtherActivity", will inherit my menu code and also "Activity".

Please try this out and let me know is this helps!